# C++ std::stringstream whitespace at the end of the command

Tags: c++, string, io

```
 void Parameters::parseCommand(std::string &input, std::vector<std::string> &params)
    {
      std::string par_str;
      std::stringstream in_str_strm(input);

      while (in_str_strm.good())
      {
        in_str_strm >> par_str;
        params.push_back(par_str);
      }
...
}
```

My Code looks like this and i have the problem that if the user enters spaces after this command the last "par_str" is pushed_back two times.

Example:

Input:
"hello   5   5    "

Elements in the String-Vector:
{"hello", "5", "5", "5"}

How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in_str_strm >> par_str` as the condition. This allows you to check the stream **after** input, so that `params.push_back(par_str);` will not execute when the input fails. Note unlike `good()`, it is converted to `true` if EOF is reached but the read succeeds, so it also works if there is no space at the end of the input.

```
while (in_str_strm >> par_str)
{
    params.push_back(par_str);
}
```